# Get the first element from the file path

Tags: r, filepath

I have the vector in a data frame

```
c("E:\\\\My Network Places.old.dat", "E:\\\\pagefile.sys", "E:\\\\Press_Dly_Diff_G_91.rbc", 
"E:\\\\TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A\\Retrospect\\Dantz", "E:\\\\TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A\\Retrospect\\TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A\\1-TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A\\AA000083.rdb", 
"E:\\\\TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A\\Retrospect\\TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A\\1-TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A\\AA000561.rdb"
)
```

In the above the length of file paths vary from just 1 to 5.  I am trying to get each level of the file path into a column in the data frame.  I tried with the first part using the following:

```
library(stringr)
df1$PF <- strsplit(df1$File.Name, "\\\\"))
df1$PFolder <- df1$PF[[1]][3]
```

But I am getting only the first `My Network Places.old.dat` for all the rows in the data frame.  How do I split the path into multiple columns based on `\\` separator and save it into separate columns within the data frame.  The desired output looks like this:

```
File.Name         FilePath1         FilePath2       FilePath3
```

The above character vector is in `File.Name` in the data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
splitstackshape::cSplit(df, "path", "\\\\+", fixed = FALSE)

#   path_1                    path_2     path_3              path_4                path_5       path_6
#1:     E: My Network Places.old.dat       <NA>                <NA>                  <NA>         <NA>
#2:     E:              pagefile.sys       <NA>                <NA>                  <NA>         <NA>
#3:     E:   Press_Dly_Diff_G_91.rbc       <NA>                <NA>                  <NA>         <NA>
#4:     E:       TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A Retrospect               Dantz                  <NA>         <NA>
#5:     E:       TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A Retrospect TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A 1-TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A AA000083.rdb
#6:     E:       TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A Retrospect TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A 1-TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A AA000561.rdb
```

Or if you already know how many columns the data will be expanded we can also use `separate`.

```
tidyr::separate(df, path, into = paste0('path', 1:6), sep = "\\\\+", fill = 'right')
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(path = x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: thank you.  This worked. thank you introducing the package splitstackshape

Answer (score 1):

Import with a separator - `"\"`:

```
library(data.table)

fread("
E:\\\\My Network Places.old.dat
E:\\\\pagefile.sys
E:\\\\Press_Dly_Diff_G_91.rbc
E:\\\\TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A\\Retrospect\\Dantz
E:\\\\TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A\\Retrospect\\TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A\\1-TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A\\AA000083.rdb
E:\\\\TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A\\Retrospect\\TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A\\1-TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A\\AA000561.rdb", 
      sep = "\\", fill = TRUE, na.strings = "")

#    V1 V2                        V3         V4                  V5                    V6           V7
# 1: E: NA My Network Places.old.dat       <NA>                <NA>                  <NA>         <NA>
# 2: E: NA              pagefile.sys       <NA>                <NA>                  <NA>         <NA>
# 3: E: NA   Press_Dly_Diff_G_91.rbc       <NA>                <NA>                  <NA>         <NA>
# 4: E: NA       TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A Retrospect               Dantz                  <NA>         <NA>
# 5: E: NA       TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A Retrospect TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A 1-TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A AA000083.rdb
# 6: E: NA       TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A Retrospect TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A 1-TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A AA000561.rdb
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `strsplit`, i.e.,

```
res <- data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(s <- strsplit(v,split = "\\\\+"),`length<-`,max(lengths(s)))))
```

such that

```
> res
  X1                        X2         X3                  X4                    X5           X6
1 E: My Network Places.old.dat       <NA>                <NA>                  <NA>         <NA>
2 E:              pagefile.sys       <NA>                <NA>                  <NA>         <NA>
3 E:   Press_Dly_Diff_G_91.rbc       <NA>                <NA>                  <NA>         <NA>
4 E:       TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A Retrospect               Dantz                  <NA>         <NA>
5 E:       TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A Retrospect TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A 1-TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A AA000083.rdb
6 E:       TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A Retrospect TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A 1-TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A AA000561.rdb
```

**DATA**

```
v <- c("E:\\\\My Network Places.old.dat", "E:\\\\pagefile.sys", "E:\\\\Press_Dly_Diff_G_91.rbc", 
       "E:\\\\TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A\\Retrospect\\Dantz", "E:\\\\TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A\\Retrospect\\TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A\\1-TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A\\AA000083.rdb", 
       "E:\\\\TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A\\Retrospect\\TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A\\1-TV_Press_Dly_Diff_A\\AA000561.rdb"
)
```